# Allow login only for active users

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8

I need to allow login only for allowed users, this is my controller:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('user', 'password');

        if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return back()->with('error', 'Usuario o Contraseña Invalidos!');
        } else if (Auth::user()->status != 1) {
            return back()->with('error', 'Usuario no autorizado');
        }

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect('home');
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::logout();
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

it works but it is allowing all the users, even those with status = 0, what am i doing wrong?

thanks for your help...

Comment: It seems you are confusing the "login" *view* and the "login" *controller method*.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment, where am I confunding the view with the controller?

Comment: In "index" controller method the `return view('login');` that would return the "login" view without auth check, and the `public function login(Request $request)` that is a separate controller method.

Comment: This case is already exemplified in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#specifying-additional-conditions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Auth::attempt` accept extra query conditions to the authentication query in addition to the user's email and password.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'status' => 1])) {
    // Authentication was successful...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your LoginControllere add this:

```
protected function credentials(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    //return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    return [$this->username() => $request->{$this->username()}, 'password' => $request->password, 'status' => 1];
}
```

Comment: Please add context to your answer to help those understand your answer and how it applies to the question asked.